# How to make the opacity of an UIElement to be changed from bottom to top gradually in the UWP application?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am building an UWP application, and I want to make an animation which changes my image’s opacity from bottom to top gradually, yet I literally don’t know how I should start this, any suggestions can be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello, `UIElement.Opacity` is usually the overall opacity modification of the element, not the difference in position like a gradient. Can you provide some pictures or other more detailed instructions to describe your intentions?